# pinging with iperf vs without iperf

Tags: linux, topology, iperf, point-to-point, mininet

I am running a basic point to point topology on mininet. If I do `h2 ping h1`, I get such rtt values:

```
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.028/0.067/0.129/0.022 ms
```

But when I ping while the iperf is measuring, my average time value is much greater. What kind of delay causes it? I am guessing transmission delay but don't understand how/why

Comment: That sounds perfectly normal. A link has a specific bandwidth, and if you must share the bandwidth on the link, each application gets less bandwidth during the shared time. Frames are sent across one frame at a time, and they must take turns on the link. If you are the only person in line, you get served right away, but if there are others ahead of you, you must wait.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but my question is that what kind of delay causes it @RonMaupin

Comment: I explained that. The packets must wait in line to be sent. A host can only serialize bits onto the wire at the bandwidth speed, and the host will send an entire frame before sending the next frame. Multiple applications must share the interface.